# Sort array of DocumentFiles faster in Android

Tags: android, sorting, documentfile

In this case I have to sort hundreds of DocumentFile objects using this method:

```
                DocumentFile[] files = documentFile.listFiles();
                ArrayList<DocumentFile> docFiles = new ArrayList<DocumentFile>();

                Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator() {
                    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                        if (((DocumentFile)o1).lastModified() < ((DocumentFile)o2).lastModified()) {
                            return -1;
                        } else if (((DocumentFile)o1).lastModified() > ((DocumentFile)o2).lastModified()) {
                            return +1;
                        } else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }

                });

                if (files != null) {
                    for (DocumentFile file : files) {

                        if (!docFiles.contains(file))
                            docFiles.add(file);



                    }
```

However, this takes way too long, about a MINUTE with 200 DocumentFile objects. I cannot understand this kind of vital class is so slow. It will have to be used more with the recent scoped storage changes.

Anyone have an idea how to get this sorting process done faster?

Comment: Every `lastModified()` call involves IPC to a `ContentProvider`. `DocumentFile` does not cache this sort of data (in part because it could change). Create yourself a `DocumentFileEntry` class (or whatever) that holds the `DocumentFile` and its last-modified timestamp. Build up a list of those, filling in the last-modified timestamp with the value of `lastModified()`. Then, sort the `DocumentFileEntry` list, so you work off of those cached timestamps.

Comment: If you want speed then do not use DocumentFile to list the content of directories to begin with. Use DocumentsContract instead. It can be up to twenty times faster.

Comment: Do you guys have examples so I can accept answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many — perhaps most — of the methods on `DocumentFile` wind up making requests of a `ContentProvider`. Such requests are not cheap. And `lastModified()` is such a method. Sorting 200 objects will result in thousands of these calls, and that is why it is taking a long time.

What you can do is:

- Create a wrapper for `DocumentFile` that holds the `DocumentFile` plus a cached copy of `lastModified()`
- Create a list of those from your list of `DocumentFile` objects, so you make one `lastModified()` call per `DocumentFile`
- Sort the list of wrappers, using the cached `lastModified()` value in the `Comparator`

Making 200 `lastModified()` calls is not going to be fast, but it will be faster than making thousands of those calls.

Comment: Extends is not possible, because `DocumentFile` constructor is package-private.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179709049

Comment: @t0m: I suggested creating a wrapper, not creating a subclass.